# Put a progressBar on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to put an indeterminate ProgressBar on the actionBar. I was using an actionView to put the progressBar like Google+ app for example.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_progress"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/action_progress"
    android:menuCategory="container"
    android:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

the problem is that the progress bar is considered as an item and therefore on a Nexus S portrait mode I have only one other item on the actionbar while on Google+ I can see two items plus the progressBar. 
How is it possible to put a progressbar using the android actionbar?

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-ProgressBars explains this very nicely

Answer (score 166, accepted):

**NOTE: [The functionality below is now deprecated in the Support Library.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(boolean))**

You need to call

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)
```

in your `onCreate()` **before setting the activity's layout**:

e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    ... // set layout etc
```

> *If you are using the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) replace **requestWindowFeature** with **supportRequestWindowFeature***

And then call

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

on your Activity whenever you want to show the progress spinner.

Comment: I have tried this, the problem is that the progress bar appears big and I want to make it small. I tried to put <item name="abProgressBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small</item> as style but it doesn't work! If I make it working, this would be the perfect solution

Comment: If the supported method is not what you want you would need to implement it yourself like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857364/how-can-i-make-a-custom-progress-bar-in-the-action-bar

Comment: with that suggestion I will consume one space on the bar. I want to understand just why cannot put a custom progressbar (just different size) using FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS

Comment: I have put a style on a progress bar as asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162481/syling-indeterminate-progressbar-on-actionbar/9162700#9162700 and it works fine :)

Comment: If you want to have a progress bar with proper size and padding, check my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519818/indeterminateprogressbar-in-actionbar-styling-padding-issue#answer-18367927

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect `ActionBarActivity` support.

Comment: For anyone else who's trying to get this to work from a Fragment, call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` from the containing Activity's `OnCreate()` and then call `getActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);` from your Fragment.

Comment: To correct the above comment, `requestWindowFeature(Window...` should be changed to  `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window...` to have it working. Well, this trick fixed it for me, at least.

Comment: And then obviously set it to false **when done**
    getActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

Comment: is it possible to set the progressBar's style to small?

Comment: How to make this support in api level 21.

Comment: `requestWindowFeature` should be called before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: @Jorge. That is incorrect. It needs to be called before `setContentView()` but can be called after the super call to `onCreate()`. Both points were illustrated in my answer. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature(int)

Comment: @Kuffs that's correct unless you use AppCompat library, in that case you it's necessary to call `requestFeature()` before `super.onCreate()`

Comment: Please post link to the documentation stating that.

Answer (score 0):

My situation required updating the progress bar from a Fragment using the Android Support Library version 4.

In my "MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity" as suggested by Jokeefe:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

before

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

In my fragment's long running task:

onPreExecute

```
actionBarActivity.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

onPostExecute

```
actionBarActivity.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
menu.clear();
actionBarActivity = (ActionBarActivity)getActivity();
actionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Not sure if this answers the OP but this is what worked for me based on the posts above. Hope this helps.

Comment: what if you don't write this: menu.clear();
actionBarActivity = (ActionBarActivity)getActivity();
actionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Without those last three lines the bar does not update with the content I need to change to and is empty.

Answer (score -1):

I have found an easiest one to show progress exactly how you need . [I found it here](http://codecops.blogspot.in/2017/09/chrome-like-progressbar-in-android.html) 
. Just use one class and place your progress bar wherever you want.