# Styling indeterminate progressbar on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-progressbar

I would like to put a progressBar on the action bar but setting

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);  
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

on `onCreate` method produces a medium size progressBar (48dip x 48dip) I guess. I want to change the size of the progressBar but I cannot find how to do it. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll need to create your own style to apply to the ActionBar. There's a great tutorial on this on the [Android Developers Blog.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) To style the intermediate progress bar, try using `indeterminateProgressStyle` and `Widget.ProgressBar.Small`. Here's a quick example.

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarIPS</item>
</style>

<style name="IndeterminateProgress" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarIPS" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/IndeterminateProgress</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I edited my response. It works now. Sorry, I hadn't tested it before. If you want to edit the smaller ProgressBar, use "Widget.ProgressBar.Small" instead. :)

Comment: it works even if now I have compatibility problems with actionbarsherlock

Comment: In ActionBarSherlock there is this attribute  <item name="abIndeterminateProgressStyle">@style/IndeterminateProgress</item>. I am very happy now :) Thanks

Comment: If you want to have a progress bar with proper size and padding, check my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519818/indeterminateprogressbar-in-actionbar-styling-padding-issue#answer-18367927

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to make ActionBarIPS's parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse" and to remove the android:background item in order for it to work with my dark ActionBar.

Comment: What should be changed to make the progress bar horizontal, as shown on some pull-to-refresh libraries (like this: https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh ) ?

Comment: Very useful answer; btw <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/ic_launcher</item> is not necessary. You have to set this, only if you want a different drawable.

Answer (score 15):

## Styled ANIMATED indeterminate progressbar icon on ActionBar:

1.Define res/values/styles.xml (This example uses Sherlock library to provide actionbar in old Android versions so, if you arent using Sherlock you should use appropiated parents to define your custom styles):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/IndeterminateProgress</item> 
        <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/IndeterminateProgress</item> 
    </style>

    <style name="IndeterminateProgress" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"> 
       <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_indeterminate_custom</item> 
    </style> 
</resource>
```

2.Define res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_custom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <rotate
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_progress_logo1"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromDegrees="-180"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="180" />
    </item>
     <item>
    <rotate
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_progress_logo2"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromDegrees="180"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="-180" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

3.Above code uses 2 images (ic_progress_logo1 and ic_progress_logo2) as custom progress indeterminated icon. You can use as much images/drawables as you want by adding new item elements. Also, you can apply differents effects/animations. More info here: [Animation Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

4.Apply style you've created using AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:name=".application.MyApplication">
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

5.Enjoy your animated custom progress indeterminate icon :D

Comment: You may want to provide a complete solution, not just a link. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with all of these solutions because I was not using `actionbarsherlock`. I leveraged off Vlasto Benny Lava's answer, which didn't work for me initially.

Here is what I did step by step:

**1)** open your styles.xml file, it should be under `/res/values/styles.xml`. If it doesn't exist create it.

**2)** 
paste in:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="myTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.MyStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.MyStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/ActionBarProgressBar.MyStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarProgressBar.MyStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Small">
        <item name="android:minWidth">28dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">28dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">28dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">28dp</item>
    </style> 
</resources>
```

One catchya I came across, you cannot use a theme name of "AppTheme" otherwise the overrides will not work. I used "MyTheme". This theme is using Holo so it has a black ActionBar as seen in image below. If you wish to have a white coloured actionbar then of course replace `android:Theme.Holo` with `android:Theme.Holo.Light` etc.

**3)** Edit `AndroidManifest.xml`.

your `<application>` must contain `android:theme="@style/myTheme"` so that the application is using your override styles from `styles.xml`

ie, my manifest application tag file looks something like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/myTheme"
    android:name="Application Name Here" >
```

Because your simply shrinking down the size of the existing progress png there is no need to export any images and move them to your drawable location etc.

Here's what mine looks like, the size of the icon is perfect for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For ActionBarSherlock you can change the indeterminate progress by parenting the Widget.ProgressBar.Small, this should work without Sherlock as well.

I fetched the drawables from the android-15 res folder in the SDK, be sure to grab progress_small_white.xml and associated resource.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
     <style name="Dark" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
         <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
     </style>

     <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
         <item name="android:indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/IndeterminateProgress</item> 
         <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/IndeterminateProgress</item> 
     </style>

      <style name="IndeterminateProgress" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"> 
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_small_holo</item> 
    </style> 
 </resource>
```

Comment: works nicely but ofcourse its not moving. how would apply the progress_small_white animation on it?

Comment: When you click on the action item, you can replace it with an actual progress bar layout:  

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"> 
    <ProgressBar android:layout_width="16dp" 
        android:layout_height="16dp" android:layout_marginLeft="12dp" android:layout_marginRight="12dp" android:layout_gravity="center" 
        style="?android:attr/indeterminateProgressStyle"/> 
</FrameLayout>

refreshItem.setActionView(myProgressBarFrameLaoutInflated);

Answer (score 2):

**To make the ProgressBar on ActionBar smaller**, what you want to do is override `Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Small` like this

```
<style name="Theme.MyStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.MyStyle</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.MyStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    ...
    <item name="android:indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/ActionBarProgressBar.MyStyle</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="ActionBarProgressBar.MyStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Small">
    <item name="android:minWidth">28dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">28dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">28dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">28dp</item>
</style>
```

and set the size to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Paste below code in your `on Create` method and run this below bar in intermediate mode.
If you want to show on progress percentage, then comment  `progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);` method and uncomment `progressBar.setProgress(65)` method and maintain your progress

```
       progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
       progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 24));
     //progressBar.setProgress(65);
     //progressBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.lock_background_greeen));
      progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

    // retrieve the top view of our application
      final FrameLayout decorView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView();
      decorView.addView(progressBar);


      ViewTreeObserver observer = progressBar.getViewTreeObserver();
      observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            View contentView = decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            progressBar.setY(contentView.getY() - 10);

            ViewTreeObserver observer = progressBar.getViewTreeObserver();
            observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to be compatible with older versions of the Android SDK so I had to keep it simple and used:

**Styles.xml**

```
 <style name="TallerTitleBarDialogThemeStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">36dp</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:theme="@style/TallerTitleBarDialogThemeStyle"
```

for the activity I need to adjust.