# Android Imageview Rotate Animation in NavigationView

Tags: android, android-animation, android-navigationview

I want to apply **Animation** in my **Image View** inside **Navigation View**.

I saw its working fine in some other apps. I have tried with following code but its not working for me.

[image]

**drawer_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
            android:title="@string/nav_menu_logout" />
    </group>

    <group
    android:id="@+id/menu_sync"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_sync_now"
            android:title="@string/string_menu_sync_now"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_menu_sync_now"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

**NavigationActivity.java**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                MenuItem menuItemSync = navigationBinding.navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_sync_now);
                menuItemSync.setEnabled(false);
                menuItemSync.setTitle(R.string.string_menu_syncing);
                mImageViewSyncing = (AppCompatImageView) menuItemSync.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.nav_sync_now_image_view);
                mImageViewSyncing.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorAccent));

                /* Create Animation */
                Animation mRotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.button_rotate);

                /* start Animation */
                mImageViewSyncing.startAnimation(mRotateAnimation);
            }
        });
```

**button_rotate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">

<rotate
    android:duration="2500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:fromDegrees="360"/>

</set>
```

**layout_menu_sync_now.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_sync_now_image_view"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sync_black" />
```

Is there any suggestion what to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create custom layout and put image view in it and start animation

Comment: I already apply custom view

Comment: no it is not custom view. you have to create horizonatal linearlayout at bottom

Comment: no. not like <item> with action layout. fully custom layout with textview and image

Comment: How can i write inside menu file

Comment: not in menu. when you declare Navigation view, below it add another layout with text and image. that way you can animate image view easily

Comment: or you can create entire menu custome. just inflate custom layout as Navigation view menu item

Comment: is it possible to animate inside navigation

Comment: yes, i did it some time ago

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28840948/6756514