# Animated ActionButton do not fire click event

Tags: android, android-animation, animator, action-button

I am animating an action button:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.iv_main_menu_icon, null);
    Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
    rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    iv.startAnimation(rotation);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_goto_menu).setActionView(iv);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

But the problem is, after applying this animation the click event isn't firing from this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put that code inside

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {

default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

not inside

```
onCreateOptionsMenu()
```

Comment: Nope. I want the animation all the time not after user clicks

Comment: I think this is what you are asking for , please check the link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28840948/4978133

Comment: I followed that answer.

Comment: Yes. But no click event. That's why I've asked this question.