# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-menu

I have notification menu icon. I need that to be animated when `onCreateOptionsMenu()` called.

While implementing, i have been facing issue like below -

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
android.view.View.setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)' on a 
null object reference.
```

Java code :

```
private Animation animation;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_screen,menu);

    animation = 
 AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.notify);

menu.findItem(R.id.notifications).getActionView().setAnimation(animation);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

home_screen.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <item
    android:id="@+id/notifications"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/notifications"/>
  </menu>
```

notify.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="180"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="500"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" />
```

Kindly let me know the solution to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14286818/10561246) answer you need to set action view first. and try to user image view as custom action view to animate your menuitem for more refrence refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28840948/10561246)