# ProgressBar under Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-progressbar

**Question Summary:** How can I make a `ProgressBar` integrated inside the `ActionBar`, like on the Chrome App?

**Details:** Look at this screenshot from Chrome:

[image: Chrome for Android screenshot]

I want to create an Action Bar just like this. Just under the Action Bar, there's a ProgressBar that fills according to page load. I've seen this example from many apps, like Feedly, but I haven't been able to create my own implementation.  I tried using Android's own APIs to create it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Request Permission to display the Progress Bar...
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
            this.setWindowContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
}
```

But this code only causes the ProgressBar to show **over** the Action Bar, like so:

[image: My App Screenshot]

So, how can I make my ProgressBar appear under the Action Bar, like on the Chrome App?

Comment: possible duplicate question of this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10755545/794088

Comment: have you found the solution yet?

Comment: screenshots for my grandma

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now a native behavior that can be obtained using [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html).

You can wrap your scrollable view with a `SwipeRefreshLayout` and then you just need to listen to *onRefresh* events:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, 
            android.R.color.holo_green_light, 
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light, 
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
}


@Override public void onRefresh() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

A nice and simple tutorial can be found in [this blog](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/).

Answer (score 55):

I wasn't fully satisfied with the accepted answer above, so I did some extra research myself.

The trick I believe they used is that they retrieved the top view in the view hierarchy called `DecorView` and added the progress bar in there. That way, the progress bar displays both over the action bar AND the content area. Note that the S.D.'s answer puts the progress bar into content area and 'steals' space from actual content, what can lead to unexpected results.

Sample **screenshots** of this implementation:

[image: ProgressBar]

[image: ProgressBarIndeterminate]

### Code

Just put this code into `onCreate` method of some activity and it should work:

```
// create new ProgressBar and style it
final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 24));
progressBar.setProgress(65);

// retrieve the top view of our application
final FrameLayout decorView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.addView(progressBar);

// Here we try to position the ProgressBar to the correct position by looking
// at the position where content area starts. But during creating time, sizes 
// of the components are not set yet, so we have to wait until the components
// has been laid out
// Also note that doing progressBar.setY(136) will not work, because of different
// screen densities and different sizes of actionBar
ViewTreeObserver observer = progressBar.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        View contentView = decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        progressBar.setY(contentView.getY() - 10);

        ViewTreeObserver observer = progressBar.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

You can play with LayoutParams' height argument to set the progressBar wider or narrower, but you might have to adjust the `-10` offset.

### Styling

Unfortunately, you can see the ugly gray background of the progress bar. To remove it, simply searching for the background by id and trying to hide it doesn't work. To remove the background, I had to create identical drawble of the system version and remove the background item.

TL;DR: Create file `progress_horizontal_holo_no_background_light.xml` and paste this drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
               android:drawable="@drawable/progress_secondary_holo_light" />
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
               android:drawable="@drawable/progress_primary_holo_light" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Copy appropriate .png drawables from `sdk/platforms/android-xx/data/res/drawable-xxx/` to your project and then in the code you can add:

```
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_horizontal_holo_no_background_light));
```

#### Extra: Indeterminate Progress Bar

Pre-KitKat versions of indeterminate progress bars are pretty ugly and laggy.
You can download new smooth progressBar called `ButteryProgressBar`. Just search for it on google (I cannot post any more links, because I am new here :[ ), add the class into your project and you can simply replace the previous ProgressBar with this code and have crispy indeterminate progress bar:

```
final ButteryProgressBar progressBar = new ButteryProgressBar(this);
progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 24));
```

You might also need to simplify this code:

```
final TypedArray ta = c.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ButteryProgressBar);
try {
    mBarColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.ButteryProgressBar_barColor,
            c.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
    mSolidBarHeight = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.styleable.ButteryProgressBar_barHeight,
            Math.round(DEFAULT_BAR_HEIGHT_DP * mDensity));
    mSolidBarDetentWidth = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.styleable.ButteryProgressBar_detentWidth,
            Math.round(DEFAULT_DETENT_WIDTH_DP * mDensity));
} finally {
    ta.recycle();
}
```

to this code:

```
mBarColor = c.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
mSolidBarHeight = Math.round(DEFAULT_BAR_HEIGHT_DP * mDensity);
mSolidBarDetentWidth = Math.round(DEFAULT_DETENT_WIDTH_DP * mDensity);
```

Hope I helped :)

Comment: The method removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener) from the type ViewTreeObserver is deprecated

Comment: @ArjunU. what should we use instead>

Comment: @PatrickGeyer see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189525/ongloballayoutlistener-deprecation-and-compatibility

Comment: I've tested the indeterminate progress bar (`ButteryProgressBar`) with `ActionBarActivity` but it doesn't work. How can I put a indeterminate progress bar under the `ActionBar/Toolbar`? This is the layout what I'm using: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26440880/1480019

Comment: @GerritHoekstra Does the classic `ProgressBar` work? If it doesn't work either, it means there is a problem with my code. But if it does work, it would be a problem with the `ButteryProgressBar` and I cannot help you there...
Anyway, can you tell me what line throws the the error? And is it runtime error or compile error? Give us more info :)

Comment: @Antimonit It's not a runtime error or compile error but the `ButteryProgressBar` is not showing. I've debugged all values and came to the conclusion that `contentView.getY()` is returning `0`. That's why the `ButteryProgressBar` is not showing. I've tried some things with `getSupportActionBar().getHeight()` and set that value to `progressBar.setY` but then the `ButteryProgressBar` appears in the middle of the `ActionBar/Toolbar`. Also tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23005863/1480019) but then also it  appears in the middle. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: @GerritHoekstra: In case the `getSupportActionBar().getHeight()` function works, you are almost there. The `progressBar.setY()` function sets the position relative to the top of the screen, including the status bar. So what you have to do is to `setY(supportActionBarHeight + Math.ceil(25 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density))`. The status bar is 25px high (mdpi) and scales with higher denisities (hdpi/xhdpi/...).Try it and tell me if it works.

Comment: Can anyone please specify the imports ?

Answer (score 25):

Extend Activities from following class to have a ProgressBar at the top(below ActionBar) of each, and a `getProgressBar()` method:

Parent class:

```
public abstract class ProgressActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        init().addView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID,init(),true);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        init().addView(view,params);
    }

    private ViewGroup init(){
        super.setContentView(R.layout.progress);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.activity_bar);
        return (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_frame);
    }

    protected ProgressBar getProgressBar(){
        return mProgressBar;
    }
}
```

Layout (progress.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/activity_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    />
  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/activity_frame"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works... for the most part. The ProgressBar does look separate from the actionbar. I had to add the `android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"` to the ProgressBar in order to simulate the "shadow" effect. But for this method, it is probably more efficient to add it to the main layout itself. Yet now it works as intended. Thanks for the hack.

Comment: @zubietaroberto Yes, You can add it to main layout if you are just using it for one activity. If you want multiple activities to have this feature, you can just extend the class shown above.

Comment: Its work for me, but the progress bar appear under the tab host, how so i can make it above the tabhost and under action bar?

Answer (score 4):

I have compiled code from this thread as well as other threads on StackOverflow and created a project that can be used to implement ButteryProgessbar as well as "pull down to refresh". https://github.com/pauldmps/Gmail-like-Pull-Down-to-Refresh

Feel free to use the code in your application.

A big thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 3):

Please use below code. just use one default style in progress bar as `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <ProgressBar 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:indeterminate="true"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , I did something similar for one of my pet apps and am not sure if that's the only way or the best way to do it , but it definitely works.

To begin with , use an overlay action bar and then set the background drawable to "null" so that the overlay action bar is transparent.

Now in you activity layout , set the top margin for your root view to "actionbar height" You can do it like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Now the action is not going to hide any of your activity content.

The next thing you have to do now is - add a header view on top of your root view with height same as the action bar. Set a background color to it. This would now be the color of your action bar and since the action bar aligns perfectly on top pf this header view.

Now you can easily put a progress bar in the header view and align it to the bottom of the header view. To the user this would look as if the progress bar is on the action bar itself , just like chrome ..