# WebChromeClient adding a progressbar -android

Tags: android, webview, android-fragments, progress-bar

Chrome has a very thin progress bar that runs while a url in loading.  Does webview have anything like that as default i can turn it on instead of making my own progress bar ?

similar to what is asked in this question: [ProgressBar under Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934010/progressbar-under-action-bar)

But i need the progress bar for a webViewfragment not an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does webview have anything like that as default i can turn it on instead of making my own progress bar ?

No.

> similar to what is asked in this question: ProgressBar under Action Bar But i need the progress bar for a webViewfragment not an activity.

That answer has nothing much to do with an activity. It is referencing the indefinite progress bar offered by the action bar. If you are using the action bar in your app, and your `WebViewFragment` extends all the way up to the action bar, you are probably best served using the action bar's indefinite progress bar.

If, however, your `WebViewFragment` is far removed from the action bar, and you want your progress indicator to be closer to the fragment, you will need to use your own `ProgressBar` widget.