# Adding a horizontal progress bar below the action bar provided by android support library v7

Tags: android, android-actionbar, progress-bar, android-support-library

I know for the first time you might think this is a duplicate question, but it is not. I have searched a lot for it, but I didn't find the answer that I need. I need to add the progress bar below the action bar. I'm using android support library v7. I tried to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592573/indeterminate-horizontal-progressbar-below-actionbar-using-appcompat) but it's using sherlock action bar so I couldn't follow it.

This is my first time to deal with progress bar, I tried to follow many tutorials but non of them worked for me. I'm not really experienced in Android programming, I would appreciate it if anyone can help me do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755224/how-to-add-progressbar-to-actionbarsherlock/10755545#10755545

Comment: @Harry the link is for sherlock actionbar, I'm not using it

Comment: @Alaa have u solved it?