# ActionBarSherlock indeterminate progress bar shows on top of action bar

Tags: android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, progress, android-theme, android-progressbar

I am getting the ABS indeterminate progress to appear, however it appears ABOVE the action bar. This is consistent with the ABS Progress demo behavior, but it is not what I want.
I want the Gmail behavior.

Here are my screenshots and ABS Demo Progress screenshots as well as my code:

- [image]
- [image]

  ```
  package com.demo.uiproofer;

  import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

  import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
  import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
  import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity{
      private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
      private AtomicBoolean isRefreshing;
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
          requestWindowFeature((long)com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          getSherlock();
          getSupportActionBar();
          //setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
          if (isRefreshing==null) {
              isRefreshing = new AtomicBoolean(false);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
          setSupportProgressBarVisibility(true);
          setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
          // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
          // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
          int id = item.getItemId();
          if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
              setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);            
              if (isRefreshing.get()==false) {
                  Log.i(TAG, "On Start Refresh Click!");
                  getSherlock();
                  getSupportActionBar();
                  setSupportProgressBarVisibility(true);
                  //setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
              }
              else {
                  Log.i(TAG, "On Stop Refresh Click!");
                  getSherlock();
                  getSupportActionBar();
                  setSupportProgressBarVisibility(false);
                  //setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
              }
              isRefreshing.set(!isRefreshing.get());
              return true;
          }
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }

  }
  ```

What I want is the Gmail behavior of the indeterminate progress bar, without the pull to refresh of course:

[image]

Comment: Please check my answer post for this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934010/progressbar-under-action-bar/23609484#23609484

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour of the ActionBar is to show the progress on top of it. The "purest" way to solve that would be to completely change the theme of the ActionBar and reverse it, which is so tricky that I have not even tried it.

There is a pretty quick workaround tough and it is to create a BaseActivity that supports a progress bar on the top of the layout.

You can find a gist with the Layout and the BaseActivity [here](https://gist.github.com/akalipetis/9945194).

P.S. Since I initially created this using the new Android compatibility library and not ActionbarSherlock, there might be small typos.

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi Antonis, I knew about the BaseActivity solution, however it is a bit hard to use because we may have 3-4 VERY DIFFERENT base activities  already for the hundreds of child activities in the app...Was trying to somehow avoid a long hierarchy chain. We did find another possible solution, a custom library that supplied this behavior. Wish I remembered which it was. I will come back to it though. So not marking it YET as correct, but I am voting up!

Comment: Hey Radu, it's nice to hear that you found a better solution, if you remember it I'd be interested to know which one.
Thanks for the upvoting!

Comment: @Radu what is the library you found?!

Comment: @Thiago Really sorry man the feature was put on hold, so I kinda lost it. However it had nothing to do with Action Bars, unfortunately.

Comment: @Radu ok... I am still not able to put the progressbar on the top of the ActionBarCompat...

Comment: @Thiago You never said you could not do the progress bar on top of the ActionBar! Btw, please note I used ABS(Action Bar Sherlock). Do not know about ABC, ppl say to use that, but ABS is tried and tested on ALL Android devices and known to work....

Comment: @Radu correct but having ABC with progressbar at the top is such a pain, I cant get it working, I only see the circular progress inside the action bar.

Comment: @Thiago Please read my last comment again. Basically my message to you is: 1. Download ABS sample - see progress bar at the top working. 2. Create your own ABS top progress bar. 3. Switch to ABC - if it does not work, blame Google and not yourself! :) We can chat or you can find me at rsavutiu@gmail.com to chat out of this thread.