# Require a progress bar in action bar

Tags: android

I need a progress bar in my action bar. I am able to get it using the following code:-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
    progress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.FALSE);
    this.setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
}
```

However, I am also seeing a spinner with progress bar. Can someone tell me how to hide the spinner.Also i need to move the progress bar below the action bar.

Comment: The Toolbar was introduced in android lollipop. Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st/26440880 and also go read this dev post(http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) at the bottom of the post you will find the toolbar.

Comment: Format well before posting question

Comment: Do you need an indeterminate progress bar or an horizontal progressbar?

Comment: i need a horizontal progress bar. I know i have added two requestWindowFeatures, but my horizontal bar does not appear without "requestWindowFeature(..)"

Comment: @shilpa I think you have set 2 style at a same time, that is why you can see spinner and progress bar both.

Comment: @pratt but if i remove the second feature, then neither progress bars are visible.

Comment: If you want a progress bar below the Action Bar, it has nothing to do with the Action Bar. Just place a progressdialog at you activity's layout.

Comment: @shilpa how it is posible? I dont think so, you have to check for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ProgressBar under Action Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934010/progressbar-under-action-bar)

Comment: @shilpa Check these https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh , https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/wiki/QuickStart-Stock

Answer (score -1):

Progress bar is used when we are supposed to perform action in background. You can use it wherever you need it. Following example may be helpful:

```
private ProgressDialog PDialog;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.examplelayout);

    new Example().execute();
}

class Example extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    // private ProgressDialog dialog;       
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(examplelayout.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // This progressbar will load util tast in doInBackground method loads
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(examplelayout.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.setTitle("In progress...");     
        pDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download);
        pDialog.setMax(100);         
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        YourMethod();//perform any action
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure this is what the OP wanted. It will show a dialog with progress bar instead, not in Action Bar.