# How to add progress bar under ActionBar (Like Google +)

Tags: android

I cant seem to find any good documentation on how to add a progress bar under the ActionBar like the Google+ App. Is there a built in way of doing this or do I have to programmatically add it in?

[image: Google + Android App]

Comment: This is useful for you [SwipeToRefresh](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/)

Comment: swipe refresh layout http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/ and also check the new refresh design of android l. You can check google io schedule app for the same

Comment: Pull to refresh is also good - https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934010/progressbar-under-action-bar