# ProgressBar is displayed in the middle of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-progressbar

I am developing an app that display news from different sources. When the news is clicked it opens an `activity` that consists of a `WebView` to deliver the Web Page related to the news. Together with the `WebView` I have implemented a `ProgressBar` to display the progress in loading the page. I do not want it to take the space of the content so I tried to implement it at the bottom of the `ActionBar`. But the result wasn't what I excepted and it is shown in the image below.

[image: <code>ProgresBar</code> In <code>ActionBar</code>]

The code I have used is like below:

```
// create new ProgressBar and style it
        final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
        progressBar.setLayoutParams(new android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams(android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 24));

        // retrieve the top view of our application
        final FrameLayout decorView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.addView(progressBar);

        ViewTreeObserver observer = progressBar.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                View contentView = decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                progressBar.setY(contentView.getY()-10);
                progressBar.setX(0);

                ViewTreeObserver observer = progressBar.getViewTreeObserver();
                observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```

I am referring to this question: [ProgressBar under Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934010/progressbar-under-action-bar)

Could you tell me what I have done wrong in the code, or some other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the offset of Progress Bar using offsetTopAndBottom.
See: [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)

Comment: I used in this form `progressBar.offsetTopAndBottom((int)contentView.getY()-10);` and now it doesn't display anything.

Comment: try changing parameter try moving downwards. I think you need to add some value to it.