# How to show Progress Bar on Action Bar in android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, progress-bar, xamarin.forms

I want to show the progress bar in my action bar. I tried to show it, but when I am trying to do it, I am getting both progress bar, spinner and horizontal in action bar.

[image]

At top blue horizontal progress bar is running and on right spinner is running. But I want only top blue progress bar below the Hubsystem logo. I don't know why spinner bar is showing.

I am using following code :

```
 RequestWindowFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.Progress);
 base.OnCreate(bundle);


 SetProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
 SetProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
 SetProgressBarVisibility(true);
```

How I can get only blue progress bar at bottom of action bar?

Comment: This may ay help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934010/progressbar-under-action-bar

Answer (score 1):

It's simple to design just add a progress bar with horizontal style to your activity's main layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/activity_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    />
  <!-- Other layouts -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Here I kept android:layout_marginTop="-8dp" because if you have the shadow to your action bar then it will adjust near to action bar. If there is no shadow then adjust according to you.

**Note: This is acceptable only if you are using ToolBar in your XML layout.
If you are doing with custom coding then do like this in your MainActivity.**

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        init().addView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID,init(),true);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        init().addView(view,params);
    }

    private ViewGroup init(){
        super.setContentView(R.layout.progress);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.activity_bar);
        return (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_frame);
    }

    protected ProgressBar getProgressBar(){
        return mProgressBar;
    }
}
```