# Show/Hide ProgresBar in ActionBar on android API lower than 11

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I want to show/hide ProgressBar in ActionBar on all android devices.
I am using android support library (android-support-v7-appcompat).

My activity extends `ActionBarActivity` and in `onCreate` it requests window feature `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` (before setting content).

On my button click I show/hide ProgressBar.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonProgress) {

        if(progress) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            progress = false;
        } else {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            progress = true;
        }

    }
}
```

This code works fine on android API higher than 11. But I have proglem with API lower than 11. The ProgressBar is not showing up. There is no error in LogCat.

I have noticed that when I show ProgressBar in `onCreate` it works. I also can hide it from `onCreate`.

Do you have solution for this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably you need to use ActionBarSherlock

Comment: I want to use just android API, not ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true)
```

if call it from fragment cast the activity for example:

```
ActionBarActivity ac =(ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
ac.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Comment: That is kinda obvious. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no action bar for apps lower than API 11.. If you use ProgressBar for Less than API 11 (Honeycomb) it does show up but it will tiny circle revolving on the top right of the title bar (thin bar on top of the app). Well, that depends on the theme.

If you want an actionbar you may want to look into an external library : ActionBarSherlock

Comment: It works when I show it in `onCreate` function. I have problem when I try to show it on button click.

Answer (score 0):

The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.

And ActionBar is added in support liabrary to allow implementation of the action bar user interface design pattern back to Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher. Use of this class requires that you implement your activity by extending the new ActionBarActivity class.

[Have a look at the official document here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

However you can achieve this by using ActionBarSherlock library.

[Check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755224/how-to-add-progressbar-to-actionbarsherlock)

[Site for ABS](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) Here you can get the sample programs ABS Library

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use android API not ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: Action Bars start from API 11, you can't use Action Bars under API 11.

Comment: Than why is there support library for them?