# Android, Progress Bar under ActionBar, and remove circle progress

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-progressbar

I am using ActionBarSherlock, and using custom view for the action bar  and i want to make progress bar, using this code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
```

but somehow the progress bar is appear above the action bar and also it put a circle progress indication at left most of action bar,

how to put the progress bar under the action bar and remove the circle indicator?

thank you

[image: the layout i want]

Comment: Thanks as in your question only i got the solution. saved me!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for the circle, is this line of code.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

And as for the progressbar this should enable it.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

As you've already done, what you need now is to alter it.

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10755545/1882855) for an example.

For a similar question with a good answer look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15073680/1882855).

Comment: Thanks @Korebian, But using  [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15073680/1882855) my progressbar is appear under the TabBar, how i can change this so it can appear above Tabbar?