# How to set a progress bar below the action bar like the chrome app?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

![ i used this code
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

i wanna know how to create a progress bar like the screenshot, please
give me some code...thanks][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBMHG.png)

[image]

Comment: Use this link may be it help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157504/put-a-progressbar-on-actionbar

Comment: i dont have to use the requestwindowfeature,all i need is to create progressbar that is positioned below the actionbar and add some codes