# Want to Show Progress Bar on action bar when every link clicked inside the webview

Tags: android, webview, progress

I have a android app with webview and i've added progress bar in the action bar which display on the first page load only. but i Want to Show Progress Bar on action bar when every link clicked inside the webview. Anybody help me???

Here is my main.java code

```
import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {
    Context mContext=Main.this;
    private WebView mWebview ;
    SharedPreferences appPreferences;
    boolean isAppInstalled = false;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       /* Progress bar */
        getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        setProgressBarVisibility(true);
        /* Progress bar */
        /* home Screen Shortcut */
        appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        isAppInstalled = appPreferences.getBoolean("isAppInstalled",false);
        if(isAppInstalled==false){
        /**
         * create short code
         */
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "T2Lead");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
        /**
         * Make preference true
         */
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isAppInstalled", true);
        editor.commit();
        }
        /* home Screen Shortcut */
        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
        mWebview  = new WebView(this);
        mWebview.setInitialScale(1);
        mWebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        final Activity activity = this;
        /** Showing Indeterminate progress bar in the title bar*/      
        activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            /*Progress Bar on title Bar */
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                 /** This prevents the loading of pages in system browser */
                return false;
            }

            /** Callback method, executed when the page is completely loaded */
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                 super.onPageFinished(view, url);
 /*
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                /** Hiding Indeterminate Progress Bar in the title bar*/
                activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                /*Progress Bar on title Bar */
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }


       public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
          if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
             String[] children = dir.list();
             for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                   return false;
                }
             }
          }

          // The directory is now empty so delete it
          return dir.delete();
       }

       /* Back Navigation */
       @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }  

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if(item.getItemId() == R.id.item1){
                mWebview.reload();
                return true;
            }
            else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.item2){
                finish();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `setWebChromeClient()` rather `setWebViewClient()` like this

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

                if(newProgress >=100){
                    activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                }else{
                    activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Better to do it this way to make it more clear: .setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility((newProgress >=100));

Answer (score 0):

#### Follow this artical : [Using the Android action bar (ActionBar) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html)

and also

**[This is Best Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9157874/1318946)**

Answer (score 0):

I created a reusable webview with progress bar, which you can find it [here](http://huluyige.blogspot.com/2013/12/android-progress-bar-webview.html)

1) Create a layout xml file : “view_progress_webview.xml” which contains a progressbar and a webview

```
<ProgressBar

    android:id="@+id/webview_progressbar"

    style="@style/SmallProgressBarHorizontal"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:visibility="gone"

    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress"/>

<WebView

    android:id="@+id/webview"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

2) Add the Style code in “style.xml”

```
<style name="SmallProgressBarHorizontal" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">

  <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/greenprogress</item>

  <item name="android:minHeight">5dip</item>

  <item name="android:maxHeight">5dip</item>

</style>
```

3)  Add a file “greenprogress.xml” in res/drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">

    <shape>

        <corners android:radius="0dip" />



        <gradient

            android:angle="270"

            android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"

            android:centerY="0.75"

            android:endColor="#ff747674"

            android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d" />

    </shape>

</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">

    <clip>

        <shape>

            <corners android:radius="0dip" />



            <gradient

                android:angle="270"

                android:centerColor="#80ffb600"

                android:centerY="0.75"

                android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"

                android:startColor="#80ffd300" />

        </shape>

    </clip>

</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">

    <clip>

        <shape>

            <corners android:radius="0dip" />



            <gradient

                android:angle="270"

                android:endColor="#4e551f"

                android:startColor="#bbcf4e" />

        </shape>

    </clip>

</item>
```

4) Create a class “ProgressWebView.java"

```
    import android.content.Context;

import android.util.AttributeSet;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import android.widget.ProgressBar;



public class ProgressWebView extends LinearLayout {



 private Context context;

 private ProgressBar progressBar;

 private WebView webView;



 public ProgressWebView(Context context) {

  this(context, null);



 }



 public ProgressWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

  super(context, attrs);

  this.context = context;

  init();

 }



 private void init() {



  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context

    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_progress_webview, this);

  progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.webview_progressbar);

  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

  webView.setWebChromeClient(new ArticleWebChromeClient());

 }



 public WebView getWebView() {

  return this.webView;

 }



 private class ArticleWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {



  public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

   if (progress < 100

     && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {

    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

   }

   progressBar.setProgress(progress);

   if (progress == 100) {

    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

   }

  }

 }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The more easy way:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        // Progress in ActionBar (if you want)
        // Add to Activity.onCreate: getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }           

});
```