# Setting progress icon inside the activity from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, progress, alarm

I'm using a `BroadcastReceiver` to check for new data on the server every 5 minutes. I would like to set a kind of progress icon in my `MainActivity`'s action bar every time a check is performed - how do I do that from the `BroadcastReceiver`?

Essentially I just want to use the `setBackgroundResource()` but I don't know how to do that from my `BroadcastReceiver`.

**Edit:** I'm starting the alarm in activity other than the activity I would like to update the progress bar and the  `BroadcastReceiver` is in the separate class.

Comment: u can do this by using runOnUIThread() method in broadcastreceiver.

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643385/how-to-update-ui-in-a-broadcastreceiver)

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9157874/3127335
You need to call setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); in onReceive(Context c, Intent i) method. You can use Intent and put extra boolean value and use it as setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility argument. (You have to probably implement BroadcastReceiver in Activity).