# show or hide progress bar in action bar which extends SherlockListFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-progressbar

I want to show and hide progress bar in action bar. Here I am extending my class with SherlockListFragment, there is no onCreate method available. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157504/put-a-progressbar-on-actionbar/9157874#9157874) but didn't working. How can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance..

Here is my code:

```
package com.geeklabs.footmark.activity.tab;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
import com.geeklabs.footmark.activity.tab.adapter.TrackAdapter;
import com.geeklabs.footmark.domain.Track;
import com.geeklabs.footmark.event.EndlessScrollListener;
import com.geeklabs.footmark.task.GetCapturedTracks;

public class CaptureListFragmentTab extends SherlockListFragment {
    private TrackAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Get tracks if not showing on UI
        if (adapter != null && adapter.getTracks().isEmpty()) {
            getTracks();
            getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        Log.i("Loading Tracks", "Loading your moments");

        adapter = new TrackAdapter(getActivity());

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // Listen for scroll change, Are we at the end of list view ?
        EndlessScrollListener endlessScrollListener = new EndlessScrollListener(
                0) {
            @Override
            protected void runTask(int currentPage) {
                // get tracks in background async task
                GetCapturedTracks getCapturedTracks = new GetCapturedTracks(currentPage, CaptureListFragmentTab.this.getActivity(), null) {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateUI(final List<Track> tracks) {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                // Notify adapter with new track list
                                if (adapter != null && tracks != null
                                        && !tracks.isEmpty()) {
                                    adapter.setTracks(tracks);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
                getCapturedTracks.execute();
                getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            }
        };
        getListView().setOnScrollListener(endlessScrollListener);
    }

    private void getTracks() {
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        // get tracks in background async task
        GetCapturedTracks getCapturedTracks = new GetCapturedTracks(0,
                this.getActivity(), null) {
            @Override
            protected void updateUI(final List<Track> tracks) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // Notify adapter with new track list
                        if (adapter != null && tracks != null && !tracks.isEmpty()) {
                            adapter.setTracks(tracks);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                          getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                        } else if (adapter != null && adapter.getTracks().isEmpty()) {
                            setEmptyText("Oops no moments captured yet ...");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        getCapturedTracks.execute();
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes as its Fragment, there is no `onCreate()` method. But you can write the same code inside `onCreateView()` method.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
       ....
       ....
}
```

Comment: How can do same in another class which extends FragmentPagerAdapter too? Is there any default method?

Comment: I am getting this exception when I run my code after implementing with above mentioned code. http://www.mediafire.com/edit/9pjorre3sjh73n6/log1.txt

Comment: @shylendra yes it will give you this exception if you inflate or initiate any views before requesting any window feature. And that's why I have given ... ... in my answer only for those stuffs.

Comment: But here I didn't inflate or initiate any views before requesting any window feature. Still getting same exception.See My  code posted above..

Comment: any solution for my query?