# How to add progress bar icon in action bar?

Tags: android

How I can attach icon of progress bar to action bar that display loading process of some Internet data?
For example:

[image]

And icon while load data

[image]

Comment: SilentKiller, only add simple icon which do nothing and read some information about it.

Comment: http://chris.banes.me/2013/01/29/snippet-animated-action-bar-items/

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/9157874/1160282

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to create a custom menu to use inside your activity.
Secondly, you have to request the feature of progress bar inside your "onCreate".

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
   // rest of your code
   [....]
}//end of onCreate
```

Then your my_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@ drawable/ic_menu_refresh "
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Refresh"
    android:visible="true"/>
</menu>
```

Back to your activity, you have to inflate this menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_refresh:
    // refresh icon clicked

    //show the indeterminate progress bar
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    // Rest of your code to do re refresh here
    [...]
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

PS: All the above code is working using the ActionBar Compat Library.

EDIT:

Ok, to hide the action bar icon do this:
-Create a menuitem outside your functions:

```
MenuItem refreshIcon;
```

Edit your onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    //Initializing menu item
    refreshIcon = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Then when you press the button change the visibility:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_refresh:
    // refresh icon clicked

    //show the indeterminate progress bar
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    //hiding action icon
    refreshIcon.setVisible(false);
    // Rest of your code to do re refresh here
    [...]
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Finally, when your data is finished updating set the visibility to "true" and hide progressbar:

```
[...] //progress inside your AsyncTask or wherever you have your update
//show Refresh Icon again
refreshIcon.setVisible(true);
//hide the indeterminate progress bar
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Comment: how i can use setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); in fragment?

Comment: i found solution,but this progress bar don't replace my menu icon and never stop

Comment: In order to access the support bar inside a fragment just add:
    getActivity.setSupport...